# Vue methods to change data discouraged by docs - but why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

According to the Vue 3.0 [guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#methods):

> Methods called from a template should not have any side effects, such
> as changing data or triggering asynchronous processes. If you find
> yourself tempted to do that you should probably use a lifecycle hook
> instead.

I'm curious why this is? I feel like it's very likely you'll want to change data on an event listener that references your own method rather than a lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what they mean is you should not call a method with side effects *during the render*, like this:

```html
<div :title="changeSomeData()">Hello</div>
```

One such problem with this is calling `changeSomeData()` during the render can mutate reactive data which will trigger another re-render of the component, potentially infinitely. It's not good code.

It isn't always clear to the programmer when the component will be re-rendered and thus when `changeSomeData()` will be called. This makes it difficult to trace the cause of some data mutation.

An event handler method is not executed during the render, instead it is only registered as an event handler and will be called later in response to that particular event. This is OK.

Answer (score 1):

They means the methods used for rendering purposes like :

```
<p>
   {{showSomeCalcul()}}
</p>
```

because the methods are used as handler for events :

```
 <button @clikc="send" >Send</button>
```